# I just want to get an HTML page using spray

Tags: scala, spray

But their documentation looks assuming I'm already familiar with Scala, Akka and Spray itself. I mean I couldn't find out how to do this simple basic thing, that I would love to have as one snippet of code in their home page...

The only thing I could find is how to build a request with their `spray-httpx`:

```
import spray.httpx.RequestBuilder._
val req = Get("http://url")
```

The object doesn't have operation to send itself to anywhere, so I'm sure I'm supposed to use Akka things to do it, but their documentation doesn't show the process. Please tell me how to do it. If `spray-can` do the same thing, I know it can, I would prefer the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example here: http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-client/

```
import spray.http._
import spray.client.pipelining._

implicit val system = ActorSystem()
import system.dispatcher // execution context for futures

val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse] = sendReceive

val response: Future[HttpResponse] = pipeline(Get("http://spray.io/"))
```

and even simpler example here: https://github.com/spray/spray/wiki/spray-client

```
val conduit = new HttpConduit("github.com")
val responseFuture = conduit.sendReceive(HttpRequest(GET, uri = "/"))
```

In both cases you have to process the result like you normally process a Future, e.g.:

```
for {response <- responseFuture} yield { someFunction(response) }
```

Comment: I'm going with the first one because the second one looks deprecated. Thank you!